# iPhone 4 Stuck on Headphones Mode

Tags: iphone, headphones

I took my headphones out of my phone after a run and I figured out that it is stuck on headphones mode. I've read the forums and tried...

to plug in and out my headphones (I even used two different pairs
I blew into the headphone port (similar to an old Nintendo system)

**Something to note:**
My alarm works and when I unlock the phone during the alarm I get the click sound.

Answer (score 7):

I have this problem happen occasionally with many of my audio "gadgets".  I generally follow troubleshooting steps in this order and have always gotten it working again.

Step one is **plugging/un-plugging headphones**.  This almost always corrects it (but apparently it has not in your case).

Step two is **power-cycling the device**.  For an iPhone, I would recommend *resetting* it by holding down both the sleep/wake and home buttons until you see the Apple logo.

Step three is **carefully checking the port for damage**, or an object that might have become lodged in there.  And if it's not fixed by this point...

Step four is **getting it serviced** by the manufacturer.  Sometimes problems are simply beyond our ability to fix them ourselves.

Comment: +1 great steps - I believe most of the times, up to step 2 is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest cause of this problem is fluff!

If you store the phone in a pocket or a bag fluff can get into the headphone socket, it doesn't cause any harm but after a while it can build up and block the connectors, when you compress the fluff against the inside of the connector the phone thinks there are headphones inside.

The solution first, and easy to do, suck the air out using you mouth or use a small pin to scrape it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after spilling some water on my pocket (ok it was a water fight), although the phone was in a slip case the headphone socket was exposed and a small droplet of water got in shorting my headphone socket. Considering you have been running, sweat or even rain water could have made it's way in.

**Solution**

In the end the only way i could get the water out was to use a bike pump with the adapter for pumping up rugby and foot balls. It is small enough to fit into the jack. (It needs to be small enough to allow for the air you pump in to come back out the sides, my little adapter is about 1.5mm thick.) Use the pump then to force the water out although be careful because the adapter is very small so the air pressure is huge. I kept the screen lit during this so i could see if anything was deforming.

Note: Do not try and blow it out as there is too high a risk of you putting in more moisture from your breath.

Also I'm not sure if the air canisters are a good idea either, then tend to make things very cold.

Comment: The football needle and tire pump worked when nothing else would. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

I spilled cola into the headphone socket. Then I read about sucking the air from the headphone port. Use your mouth and suck the air inward; don't blow air into the port, as you may put more moisture into it by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Forget mechanical methods.. and why blow air in instead of drawing it out?
I just put a vaccuum over the jack outlet, cupped around the large hose end with my hands and presto... months of problems over!  (And I didnt have to buy compressed air).

Answer (score -3):

To get out of headphone mode, try to turn on airplane mode and turn it off; or update your iPhone system.

Good luck.